# How do HD voice calls work?

Tags: calls

Most of the operators now support HD voice on Android devices. I was wondering about the following points:

1. How can an Android user be sure that a call is HD without guessing from the audio quality?
2. Does the phone hand over calls from HD to normal call and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

None of the carriers in the US support this that I know of. But according to the [android supported codec page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), [AMR-WB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_Wideband) (Adaptive Multi-Rate Wideband) is supported by android devices. As long as the carrier is actually using the "spec" to transmit the "HD Voice" over the GSM/CMDA network, there is nothing special that needs to be done for android devices, it will support both Normal and HD calls.

To explain a little further. When an HD call comes in on a device that supports AMR-WB, and it is enabled (based on the comments below that some may not have support enabled), nothing has to be done on the device side. All that is sent to the device is an audio stream, the stream is in the AMR-WB format and the device decodes that automatically. Because it is an audio codec specification and the support for that exists on the device you are able to send/receive using this codec.

Comment: you comment is availability of technology on device and operator but There are some devices say S2(international version) which requires explicit enabling of wb-amr support..there must some gateway where it detects the behavior of the call.. I dont no if the same applies to Galaxy s2 US version(skyrocket)

Comment: ok, but your question was not if it has to be enabled on the device, your questions was how does it detect it, and does it handle the 2 different types of calls, which I answered. No carrier in the US supports HD voice, so even if you have to enable it on the US version of the SGS2, it wont do anything.

Comment: I jus now found that there are more than 60 mobile devices world wide(status as of Nov-2011 might have grown now)  from different OEM which supports HD voice. Here is the difference. ON ANDROID some devices needs to be enabled explicitly and some are enabled by default. Now the point 1. how to detect on default enabled devices.

Comment: I have added to my original answer and I hope that helps explain it.

Comment: Edited my question with more clarity